# How to simplify this expression containing the greatest integer function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\lfloor x+1\rfloor^2+\lfloor x\rfloor^2-2\lfloor x\rfloor-15=0$
where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the floor function

which is
$\lfloor x \rfloor^2+2\lfloor x \rfloor+\lfloor x\rfloor^2-2\lfloor x+1\rfloor$

beyond which I'm stuck, could someone help?

Comment: prove that floor(x+1) = floor(x)+1  . Then substitute floor(x)=t in your equation, and solve for t. Retain valid values of t and use them to obtain valid x

Comment: $[x+1] = [x]+1$

Comment: Thanks a lot !!